# Issue with BigQuery API for querying results

Tags: google-bigquery

With reference to the links below :
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults

I am trying to pull the table data through the bigquery API with pagination via pagetoken and maxResults as input.
However, every-time the results is giving the same pageToken value and returning maxResults no of rows everytime. It is not fetching the results as expected. Basically it goes on an infinite loop even if the table has X no of rows.

I have already tried using tabledata/data API with pagination and it works perfectly.

Anyone has faced this issue? What is the channel to escalate this issue?

Note: Iam trying this through postman and am not using any client libraries for java as am trying to mimic this in my specific application with a https client utility.

The behavior is similar when tried from my application as well as from postman.

Regards.
KP

Comment: This sounds unexpected. Have you tried to use the UI on the right side of  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults page to repro the issue? I asked because this API has nothing special than tabledata.list (you will find their pageToken to be interchangeable), if tabledata.list works for you, so should this one.

Comment: How are you getting the pageToken?